# Probability of getting the same vector result

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is part of a mathematical puzzle I was given to me by a friend a while ago and I can't work out how to solve it. Does anyone have any ideas?

For a given vector $v \in \{-1,1\}^n$ we consider the following $n$ sums. $$S_j=\sum_{i=0}^j v_i - \sum_{i=j+1}^{n-1} v_i \text{ for } 0 \leq j \leq n-1.$$

For example if $v = (-1,1,1)$ then $S=(-3,-1,1).$

Now let $f(S)_j = 1$ if $S_j>0$ and $0$ otherwise. So for our example vector $v$ we have that $f(S)=(0,0,1)$

> For two uniformly randomly selected vectors $v,w \in \{-1,1\}^n$ what
>   can we say about $$P(f(v) = f(w)).$$

We know that $P(f(v) = f(w)) \geq 2^{-n}$ as this is the probability that $v=w$.  This gives a lower bound, but what upper bound can one find?

Comment: The first few probabilities are $a_n/2^{2n}$ with $a_n=2$, $6$, $8$, $32$, $52$, $234$, $436$, $2064$, $4256$, $20552$, $45784$, $222320$, $526164$, $2552026$, $6340468$, $30621504$, $79170464$, $380194952$, $1016243692$, $4850117720$, $13335586804$, $63247340032$, $178178098552$, $839888120192$, $2416648791252$, $11324688214184$. That sequence isn't in OEIS. The probabilities seem to be somewhat above $2^{−n/2}$. [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/8317e8cca604429ebcd5) to produce those numbers.

Comment: @joriki That is very interesting, thank you. Any bound of the form $2^{-n/c}$ for $c > 1$ would already be really great..

Comment: It's not quite clear from the data whether such a bound obtains. The next few values are $33195820877900$, $154693188780072$, $460971981557088$. Fitting a line to a log plot yields a reasonably good fit with $a_n\sim2^{1.845n}$, corresponding to probabilities $\sim2^{-0.155n}$, but there also appears to be a slight upward trend, so it's not clear whether this will hold or whether there's a slowly changing $\log n$ term or so that will mess it up.

Comment: Ah, I realize now that I don't know whether you're looking for an upper or lower bound :-) So in case you're looking for a lower bound, you're in luck; it looks like any deviations from the $2^{-0.155n}$ fit at very high $n$ are likely to be upward.

Comment: @joriki Sorry I should have been clearer. I am looking for an upper bound.

Comment: Observation: If $v$ and $w$ have all $1$s in their first halves, and the same number of $1$s in their second halves, then $f(v)=f(w)$. This gives an improved lower bound of around $2^{-n/2}$ for the probability in question - maybe something like $2^{-n/2}/n$.

Comment: Half-baked idea for an upper bound: the places where the coordinates of $f(v)$ change from $0$ to $1$, or vice versa, seem to constrain $v$ reasonably strongly: the two sums on either side of the split are close to equal. Perhaps one can sort vectors according to the places where these bit changes occur?

Comment: One more number, $a_{30}=2136846713435746$.

Comment: There cannot be an upper bound of the form $2^{-\rho n}$ for $\rho\gt0$: For even $n=2k$, counting only the vectors that sum to zero and have only positive partial sums $\sum_{j=0}^l$ (except at $l=0$ and $l=n-1$) yields the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_{k-1}\sim4^k/k^{3/2}\sim2^n/n^{3/2}$. These vectors all have the same $f$, so squaring their number shows that $a_n$ goes at least as $2^{2n}/n^3$, so the probability goes at least as $n^{-3}$, which decays more slowly than any exponential.

Comment: @joriki That's really surprising given the numerics!

Comment: @phoenix: Well, it was $\sim2^{-0.155n}$ with an upward trend, and I'd warned that the upward trend might mess up the exponential behaviour...

Comment: @phoenix: Sorry, once I saw that $a_n$ was close to $2^{2n}$, I should have plotted the probabilities $a_n/2{2n}$ instead. They actually nicely confirm the combinatorial analysis.

Comment: @GregMartin: My answer builds on your observation about the bit changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is in $\Omega\left(n^{-2}\right)$, and apparently also in $O\left(n^{-2}\right)$ (and thus in $\Theta\left(n^{-2}\right)$).

I'll focus on odd $n$ because it makes things easier, but I believe with some slight complications similar considerations apply to even $n$.

If we add another entry for $j=-1$ to $S$, we have $S_{-1}=-S_{n-1}=:\sigma$. Moving from $j=-1$ to $j=n-1$, we successively transfer each entry of $v$ from the negative sum to the positive sum, with a change of $\pm2$ in each step. Two such sequences lead to the same $f$ vector iff they have the same zero crossings. Thus the probability can be obtained as $2^{-2n}$ times the sum, over all possible zero crossing sets, of the square of the number of sequences with exactly those zero crossings.

For odd $n=2k+1$, there are an odd number of zero crossings (since $\sigma\ne0$). Consider the term with one zero crossing. Imagine $S_j$ plotted against $j$, and reflect the part of the graph under the $j$ axis at the axis to flip it above the axis. Since $S_{-1}=-S_{n-1}$, that makes the graph match up at $-1$ and $n-1$, so we can now consider it cyclically. If we fix the position of the one zero crossing, that fixes the two values adjacent to it, and the number of possibilities for the remaining values, given that they must not cross the axis, is given by $C_k$, the $k$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics). We need to square this to get the contribution to the probability, and then multiply by $2n$ ($n$ for the position of the zero crossing and $2$ because the negative part can be on either side of the zero crossing). Thus the contribution to the probability for one zero crossing is

$$
2^{-2n}\cdot2n\cdot\left(\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}k\right)^2
$$

The asymptotic behaviour of the Catalan numbers is

$$
C_k \sim \frac{4^k}{k^{3/2}\sqrt{\pi}}\;,
$$

so that contribution is asymptotic to

$$
\frac4\pi\frac1{n^2}\;.
$$

The remaining terms can be calculated likewise – for all odd $m$, we'd have to sum, over all possible positions of $m$ zero crossings, the square of a product of $m$ Catalan numbers counting the numbers of non-zero-crossing connections between the zero crossings. While there are of the order of $n^m$ ways to choose the positions of the zero crossings, almost all of these involve $m$ factors of the order of $(n/m)^{-3}$ from the Catalan numbers, so not much is gained. This is of course not a rigorous argument for the probability being in $O\left(n^{-2}\right)$, but it could perhaps be turned into one, and in any case the numerical results confirm that the term for one zero crossing is the dominant one.

Here's a doubly logarithmic plot of the probabilities up to $n=30$ (right-click for options to display it in full resolution):

[image: doubly logarithmic plot of probabilities]

The pink boxes are for even $n$, the red crosses are for odd $n$, the green line is a fit to the results for odd $n$ with slope $-2$ (corresponding to $n^{-2}$), and the blue line is the above result for the dominant term, $(4/\pi)n^{-2}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this (sadly I can't upvote twice :) ). What is the best rigorously provable upper bound you can get currently?

Comment: @phoenix: Unfortunately, none of this yields a provable upper bound. The contribution for one zero crossing can be evaluated explicitly and yields the $n^{-2}$ lower bound, but I don't know whether the higher contributions can be evaluated in closed form. The numerical evidence that they also go at most as $n^2$ is pretty strong, but I wouldn't know how to prove that.